# Product images missing on category page

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.6

I have a problem with product images. Although they're displaying correctly in the admin panel and on product page, for some reason they fail to load on category page. It looks like Magento can't generate an image in `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` - but has no problem with that on product pages.

Does anyone have any idea why it may be happening? I already tried setting 777 permissions on `pub/media/catalog/product/cache`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following command in the CLI from your Magento installation's root folder:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

It should fix it.

I've already reported that bug to the magento support team.

EDIT: More info, for us this happens when we use the import tool to import products in 2.1.6. Running the CLI command above fixes the issue. I've already reported it to the Magento team.

Comment: I already apply it but not showing missing product image on detail page